# Graphic app in C++ and code in C **Qt Programming**

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, sockets

i have an application to realise with sockets in c, and i'm confortable with C++ and Qt, is it possible to do both C and C++ on Qt.

there is a sample from the code is on C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT 9600

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int sock_cnx; /* Socket pour ouverture de connexion */

    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    struct sockaddr_in clientaddr;

    int newfd;
    char buf[1024];
    int nbytes;
    int addrlen;
    int i, j;

    /* Ensemble des descripteurs qu’on souhaite surveiller en lecture */
    fd_set surveil_fds;

    /* Ensemble des descripteurs qu’on va utiliser dans SELECT */
    fd_set read_fds; 

    /* Memorise le plus grand descripteur : a utiliser dans SELECT*/
    int fdmax; 

    addrlen = sizeof(clientaddr);

    /* Ouverture de la socket du serveur */
    if ((sock_cnx = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) == -1){
        perror("Erreur socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    bzero(&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr));

    serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl (INADDR_ANY);

    bzero(&(serveraddr.sin_zero), 8);

    /* Bind */
    if (bind(sock_cnx, (struct sockaddr *)&serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) == -1) {
        perror("Erreur Bind");
        exit(1);
    }
    ........
    return 0;
}
```

i already created my interface for the app on Qt.

Comment: Qt also has [support for sockets](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpsocket.html), it might be preferable to use that if you already have a Qt app. One advantage is that you can use signals to handle incoming data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within you Qt/C++ application, you can include you C-file as follows:

```
extern "C" {
#include "myCHeaderFile.h
} /* extern "C" */
```

You can than simply access the C-functions within your C++/Qt file.

Comment: Okay i will test it.

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks. 
Just will now have to use the appropriate sockets library for windows.